# click on the dialog box. The following can respond to click events

Tags: android, dialog

I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this。
I think the user clicks the outside of the dialog when the outside of the control can respond to click events, and dialog disappears.But I think it seems impossible because it is two view layers that can not pass events.

Comment: Please provide some code to show what you have tried so far. The question is not very clear.

Comment: Every dialog/vies absolves the click, if you don't want it to do so then make the clickable as false.

Comment: I mean click on the outside area of ​​dialog, you can pass this click event

Answer (score 0):

Use `dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside (false);` to prevent the dialog from being canceled when outside if it is touched.

If you want to pass the touch event to other views when clicked outside, do not use alert dialog at all. Just use a simple Layout like `RelativeLayout` (maybe with some elevation). And show or hide it using the method `setVisibility`.

Comment: thanks your answer, but what i mean is to let this click event be passed to the next view, not to cancel the dialog

Comment: Well, but I want to give the user a hint, if you follow what you say, I need to add the code in each layout.

Comment: Alert dialog aren't capable of that. use some tooltip libraries like https://github.com/ViHtarb/Tooltip

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I know this can use popupwindow pop-up prompt box, but I do not want the cue box attached to a view above

Comment: Sorry that nothing helped you. If you want so many customizations, you should create your own custom view.

Comment: Thank you very much for giving me so much advice, and I finally inherited BaseActivity for all activities, showing that message in BaseActivity

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you are expecting, but if you are using `AlertDialog` for creating dialog boxes, setting `setCancelable()` to `false` will do the trick.

Eg:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder();
...
builder.setCancelable(false);
...
AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
dialog.show();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I mean click on the outside area of ​​dialog, you can pass this click event.